# Find the value of a circle with d3js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Hello i am new user of D3js and use version 7, i have a problem to find the value of a circle pointed by the mouse.

I have find it with the following code :

```
.on("mousemove", (event, d) => {console.log("x10", d); )//WORKING}
```

inside this code :

```
d3.selectAll('circle')
  .on('mouseover', function(e, d) {
    d3.select(this)
    //.on("mousemove", (event, d) => {const x10 = console.log(event.currentTarget)+console.log("x10", d.measurement); })//WORKING
    .on("mousemove", (event, d) => {console.log("x10", d); })//WORKING
    //.console.log("A",x10) 
    .style('fill', 'red');
      
  })
```

and so i can get the information (the value 60.49) i need on the console :

```
{
    "date": "2022-10-25T21:00:00.000Z",
    "measurement": 60.49
}
```

but i would like to get the returned value in a var or const, so i have tried this :

```
.on("mousemove", (event, d) => {var A = console.log("x10", d); })//NOT WORKING`
```

So if someone of you can help me.Thx

Comment: Do you mean d3js? https://d3js.org

Comment: Yes, i just change it to be more clear

Answer (score 0):

If this part is working:

```
.on("mousemove", (event, d) => {console.log("x10", d); )//WORKING}
```

then you could use it to call your own function instead of console.log

```
d3.selectAll('circle')
  .on('mouseover', function(e, d) {
    d3.select(this)
    .on("mousemove", (event, d) => logMeasurement(event, d))
    .style('fill', 'red');
})

function logMeasurement(event, d){
    var a = d.measurement 
    console.log(a)
}
```

Comment: Hi thanks it's working, now i need to understand how to implement it on my code.

Comment: Ok thanks i have deleted it. I am working on my code and wil post a new question if i don't succeed

Comment: I try to implement it but your solution is giving me some trouble. When used like this me code looks like blocked inside this loop and didn't get out. i want just to have the value and then getting out.. if you have any idea

Comment: To know exactly what is going wrong we would need the HTML that shows your D3 graph. It's a bit hard to debug only the `mouseover` code without a way to test it.

Comment: Hi thanks, i have created a new post here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74292045/probleme-with-mouse-over-with-3d-js